# Addition on array of char

Tags: c++, c

This is probably a stupid question. Playing with C++ and find this line of code that makes me a little confused

```
char buffer[7] = {'0', '1', '0', '9', '0', '1'};

// It prints 010901
printf("%s", buffer);

// It prints 0901
printf("%s", buffer+2);
```

Why we can (+ 2) the buffer variable and it's like shifted 2 character to the right?

Comment: you want to print as if we shifted all elements by 2 to the right?

Comment: I just want to know why I can do buffer+2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a context such as that one, the array name `buffer` "degrades" to being just a pointer to the first value. Since C and C++ support pointer arithmetic, and strings are represented just as pointers to arrays of characters, it's fine.

Note the terminating `'\0'` character, which is implied since you specify a larger size than you provide initialization data for.

Still, your code can be simplified to:

```
const char buffer[] = "010901";
```

You can visualize it like so:

```
               +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
buffer ------> | '0' | '1' | '0' | '9' | '0' | '1' | '\0 |
               +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                              ^
                              |
                              |
                         buffer + 2
```

Comment: Is it really just luck? If the array was bigger than the amount of elements specified, aren't the other elements be default initialized which would make them zero?

Comment: %s will still print until the terminating char. %c will give a char, but i think thats not what he meant

Comment: Hi, I know exactly what unwind meant. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Yexo Thanks! I always manage to confuse myself about that one.

Comment: @SoNoob what was the question? i thought you wanted to print it like "010109"

Comment: @Infested I just need an explanation, why I can +2 the buffer variable ? I am not asking how to print the string. Cheers

Comment: The Pointer Anti-Defamation League objects to the terms “decay” or “degrade” when referring to array conversion. Pointers are first-class types and deserving of all the privileges and benefits thereof. The conversion of arrays to pointers is not a decay or a degradation. Indeed, since many people find the pointers to be more useful than the arrays, and that is the motivation for the conversion, it can be said to be an upgrade. (Seriously, just say the array is converted, the same way the C standard does.)

Answer (score 1):

Expressions of array type often undergo array-to-pointer conversion. Basically, the name `buffer` here can be converted to a pointer to its first element. That's what happens in both cases. The array is converted to a `char*` and then `printf` interprets that as pointing to the first character in a C-style string.

In the second case, after the conversion to a pointer, you are adding 2 to that pointer. This gives you a pointer to the 3rd element. `printf` again treats this as a C-style string but starting from the 3rd character of the array you created.

At first I thought that you had a problem with your string not being null-terminated. However, your code is okay because the array is of size 7 and the last element will be set to 0 because you do not specify an initializer for it. However, this is confusing. I recommend you instead declare your array like so:

```
char buffer[] = "010901";
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ defines an implicit array-to-pointer conversion; that is, an array is implicitly convertible to a pointer to its first element (element with index 0). This means your code is basicaly iterpreted like this:

```
printf("%s", (&buffer[0]) + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[7] = {'0', '1', '0', '9', '0', '1' , '\0'};
```

An array name in C is basically also a pointer to the array location

`buffer[i]` is translated as `*(buffer+i)` i.e. add `i` to the pointer value 
[follows pointer arithmetic]. So, it gives the address at that location.
`printf` will print a `%s` until it encounters a `\n`. Hence, the output.

Check [this](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) to know about pointers and arrays

Answer (score 0):

You need to nul-terminate that string, bro!

```
char buffer[7] = {'0', '1', '0', '9', '0', '1', '\0'};

// It prints 010901
printf("%s", buffer);

// It prints 0901
printf("%s", buffer+2);
```